# No resource found that matches @drawable/test err android studio

Tags: android, drawable

I've tried all solutions. Finally decided to post this question.

The situation is as follows:

My drawable has test.png image which I use in my project.
In eclipse it works perfectly but in Android Studio it doesn't work.
Also I'm not getting any compiler error.
I am getting only this type of error almost 54 times when cradle build. As this image is set of as background to 54 screens. :(
What could be the problem?

Comment: please post codes with error

Comment: There's no compile time error for src=@drawable/test ..so its worth less. And it's working fine with eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the extension part. 
For example if your image is called mimg.png in your 
resource files you should access it via @drawable/mimg. 
**Edit** 
If in eclipse is fine, then create the project new and add file by file. I also had this issues and after some tries ai gave up and created new and after added file by file.

As an alternative please check if you add it in other drawables folders. 
That's it.

Comment: Isn't this the same answer as the one I just gave?

Comment: Guys I've updated the question. As I've mentioned Ive imported my eclipse project which is running fine in eclipse..

Comment: Considering my current network connection, that might have happened. Is there a problem?

Comment: @Wana Ant I've tried that too.. Moving it to other drawable resulted into crunching PNG type of error. BTW thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference your drawable without the extension: Like this:

```
android:src="@drawable/test"
```

Remove the image extension from your xml file and try that please!

Comment: I haven't put .png extension. Sorry I mistakenly put it in question title. I'm getting no RSC found that matches name in src in @drawable/test ... Is the problem